# Efficient way to evaluate numerically product sines functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I'm trying to perform integration of the following matrix.

```
contL = 1; contC = 1;
    K = ConstantArray[0, {20*20, 20*20}];
    For[m = 1, m <= 20, m++,
     For[n = 1, n <= 20, n++,
       For[p = 1, p <= 20, p++,
        For[q = 1, q <= 20, q++,
          K[[contL, contC]] = m^2 p^2 Sin[m x] Sin[n y] Sin[p x] Sin[q y];
          contC++
          ];
        ];
       contC = 1;
       contL++;
       ];
     ]
NIntegrate[K, {x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}]
```

Someone knows how to evaluate that integration faster? It is taking heavy time to evaluate. I already tried to use `Method -> "Trapezoidal"`, but it yet doesn't improved the computation time.

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Your array is *huge*. Have you tried to evaluate the integral symbolically?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, yes. It was slower than NIntegrate. Further I need evaluate 9 arrays like that. Would you know another approach?

Comment: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)

Comment: Re @AccidentalFourierTransform's suggestion: Consider `Integrate[
 m^2 p^2 Sin[m x] Sin[n y] Sin[p x] Sin[q y], {x, -1/2, 
  1/2}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}]` and `Integrate[
 m^2 n^2 Sin[m x] Sin[n y] Sin[m x] Sin[n y], {x, -1/2, 
  1/2}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, I observed that your matrix can be represented as `KroneckerProduct` of smaller matrixes which are themselves `KroneckerProduct`s (or `TensorProduct`s) of vectors:

```
Ux = Table[m^2 Sin[m x], {m, 1, k}];
Vx = Table[p^2 Sin[p x], {p, 1, k}];
Uy = Table[Sin[n y], {n, 1, k}];
Vy = Table[Sin[q y], {q, 1, k}];
Ax = KroneckerProduct[Ux, Vx];
Ay = KroneckerProduct[Uy, Vy];
T = KroneckerProduct[Ax, Ay];

K == T
```

> True

The integrations in `x` and `y` are independent of each other, so we could compute `Ax` and `Ay` first, requiring $2 k^2$ `NIntegrate`s instead of $k^4$ in your original code. However, we can actually do the integrations symbolically first and numericize the resulting expressions. If you want that really fast, you can create a `CompiledFunction` for the numericization; this will also guarantee that `Ax` and `Ay` are packed arrays so that `KroneckerProduct[Ax, Ay]` evaluates quickly.

Creating the compiled function:

```
Block[{a, b, m, n},
  With[{
    mmcode = N@Integrate[Sin[m x] Sin[m x], {x, a, b}],
    mncode = N@Integrate[Sin[m x] Sin[n x], {x, a, b}]
    },
   cf = Compile[{{m, _Real}, {n, _Real}, {a, _Real}, {b, _Real}},
      If[m == n,
       If[m == 0, 0., mmcode],
       If[m == 0 || n == 0, 0., mncode]
       ],
      CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True
      ];
   ]
  ];
```

Computing `Ay`, `Ax`, and `T`:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  Ay = Outer[cf[#1, #2, -1/2, 1/2] &, Range[k], Range[k], 1];
  Ax = Ay KroneckerProduct[#, #] &[Range[1., k]^2];
  T = KroneckerProduct[Ax, Ay];
  ]
```

> 0.001463

I did not wait for the result for integrals over `K` in case of `k = 20`, but for `k = 5`, it took about `3.8639` seconds on my machine, while my method took only `0.000056` seconds, a speed-up of almost $69\,000$. Also, `T` should be precise up to machine precision as there is no numerical integration employed at all (so all errors stem only from the very few floating point operations `+`, `-`, `*`, from the approximations of `Sin` and `Cos` and from division by integers (have a look at `mncode`).

Comment: Kronecker products sure are neat; a lot of things simplify greatly as soon as you recognize the appropriate structure applies.

Comment: Perfect, @Henrik! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! =)